# Javascript only runs after page refresh

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

I am looking for help since my javascript only runs after I am reloading the webpage. The script is a lens connected to the cursor. If you hover over the image it should show an enlarged section of the same image in another (+) div on the right next to it. It only works on the first page perfectly:

[example of working javascript](http://krystiansokolowski.com/uniformity_one_a.html)

If I am using the same script on another page, this happens:

[example for non working script](http://www.krystiansokolowski.com/uniformity_one_c.html)

if you reload the second example, the script all of a sudden works.

Do you have any ideas what is going wrong?

Thats the script:

```
   <script>
    function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
    var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
    img = document.getElementById(imgID);
    result = document.getElementById(resultID);
    /*create lens:*/
    lens = document.createElement("DIV");
    lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
    /*insert lens:*/
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
    /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
    cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
    cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
    /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
    result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
    result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
    /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
    lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
    img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
    /*and also for touch screens:*/
    lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
    img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
    function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
    }
    function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
    }
    }

</script>       


      <script>
  // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
  if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
      height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
      slug: "UrU9S"
    }], "*")
  }
</script>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: .. both pages seem to work for me in Firefox? Anything in the dev console?

Comment: urgent because I am trying to figure it out since days and I am breaking my head above it! sorry for inconvenience!

Comment: no nothing in the dev console. I was checking the page with Safari and Chrome and there it just doesn't function

Comment: The _second_ page - http://www.krystiansokolowski.com/uniformity_one_b.html - doesn't seem to work, but the first and third do? Is that it?

Comment: exactly, they just seem to work randomly, thats it